# How do I display the current value?

Tags: html

I'm using this code:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" name="points">
```

How do I display the current value in the slider?

Comment: Do nothing. The current value *is* displayed (in Chrome it is represented by the position of the handle within the bar of the slider).

Comment: It doesn't.And neither this input type work on firefox I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the concrete number you could have a span or something over top the input and use jquery to handle the onchanged event.

HTML:

```
Price: <input id="price" type="text" value="10.50" readonly /><br/> 
Quantity: <input id="qty" type="text" value="1" readonly />
<input id="rangePoints" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1"/><br/><br/> 

Total Price: <input type="text" id="total" readonly />
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#rangePoints").change(function() { 
        var qty = $("#rangePoints").val(); 
        var price = $("#price").val();
        $("#qty").val(qty);
        $("#total").val(qty*price);
    });
});
```

[Working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NL5KC/2/)

Comment: Ok, suppose, I want to multiply the currentvalue with a predefiend number and then display it.How would that function ?

Comment: it's as simple as in the jquery where I have .text(test.val() <add multiplier here>). I'm confused what you're trying to do with the slider where the actual value isn't good enough. You have the ability to set a min and max a specific value, and you can have a step so that only certain numbers show up. What do you need to multiply by

Comment: I was doing this :- Quantity * price(per 1 article)

Answer (score 1):

The [range input type](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/forms.html#type-range) is supported only by newer browsers. But with a bit of JavaScript magic you can make it accessible for older browers too, you don't even need [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in order to do this.

In JavaScript, add the following snippet:

```
function updateCurrentValue(val) {
    document.getElementById('currentValue').value=val; 
}
```

And then, in the HTML add another [input element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html) where to show the current value of the slider:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" name="points" onchange="updateCurrentValue(this.value);">                                                       
Current value: <input type="text" id="currentValue">
```

Comment: Ok, suppose, I want to multiply the currentvalue with a predefiend number and then display it.How would that function ?